# How to install old version of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

This started happening today for absolutely no reason. Worked perfectly last week. I didn't touch the machine.

I have an issue described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309125/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-mongodb) and need to downgrade in order to be able to upgrade. Currently I'm not able to enter the shell as it exits with error #4

`need to upgrade database admin with pdfile version 4.22, new version: 4.5`

If I run it with `--upgrade` I get:

```
ERROR: error: exception cloning object in admin.system.users system.users entry must have either a 'pwd' field or a 'userSource' field, but not both obj:{ _id: "nod$
exception in initAndListen: 2 system.users entry must have either a 'pwd' field or a 'userSource' field, but not both, terminating
```

I'm trying `sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.2.10`but it doesn't work.

Can anyone direct me to a command I can use to install version 2.2.10?

Comment: Honestly you are so far behind (current is 3.6) that you should just import your data into a fresh install of a more much recent version. The [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community) appears to only have 2.7 as its oldest version.

Comment: TBH you would be happier just biting the bullet and migrating to Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the repo list

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10  
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Then re-run  `sudo apt-get install mongodb=2.2.7`

That should work. The repo list file was the differentiating step which you've missed

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work still :( .. same result

Comment: Which error are you receiving, the one posted here or on the one about a missing version?

Comment: missing version, apologies should have posted it in the main post.